# How to use file from a collection as an image and as a video?

Tags: powerapps

I have an excel table which has a column "File [File]" that is used as a data source and pulled into power apps into a collection. This column will sometimes have pictures and other times have videos.

An example of a cell in excel is .\folder\folder\pic.png or .\folder\folder\vid.MP4

If I put it as the source for an image control, it doesn't work, though if I put them into their own column as [image], the pics show up though with a multi-second load time but nothing shows for the videos.

I know I will need to selectively make visible image/video controls based on the type of file it is and that should be easy enough with string parsing.

But how do I do the rest?

1. use the file as described to feed an image control.
2. use a file as described above to feed a video control.
3. For what I would like to do with it, I'd love to be able to show an image control for the vids and pics for the gallery then when clicked, I'll navigate to another screen where just that file will be shown as either the image or video it is.

The first two are the main goal, 3 would be nice but I don't know if it is possible.

The collections are being used to feed galleries in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options for passing an image to an Image control:

1. As a URL to a web accessible location
2. As a media name of an image stored in the PowerApp media folder
3. As a base64 string

And for Video it is the first two (URL or media name).

PowerApp is a web app and therefore doesn't have access to the client's filesystem. The two options you have are adding all the images and videos into the Media folder or add all your images and videos to a web location (like SharePoint, OneDrive, website etc...) and then updating your Excel to reflect their Media name (in the media folder) or URL.

Comment: The excel file I mention, and the associated .\folder etc. files are all on onedrive for business already.
I'll add that to my question since it wasn't clear apparently.

Comment: Ensure the URLs for the images/videos are full absolute links to each file and that the files are accessible/shared by all users of your app.